# NHibernate query for matching all tags

Tags: nhibernate, tags, hql, criteria

Here are my relevant classes:

```
public class Item {
    public virtual int Id { get; protected set; }
    public virtual IList<Tag> Tags { get; set; }
}

public class Tags {
    public virtual int Id { get; protected set; }
    public virtual string Name { get; set; }
    public virtual IList<Item> Items { get; set; }
}
```

These are mapped with a many to many association.  The intermediate table is named ItemsToTags.

Here's the question:

> Given a list of strings, how do I create an NHibernate query that returns all `Item`s that have all the `Tag`s with `Name`s matching all the strings in the given list?

This is the function signature:

```
IList<Item> GetItemsWithTags(IList<string> tagNames);
```

I need something like:

```
from Item item
where !tagsNames.Except(
    from item.Tags select item.Tags.Name
).Any()
select item
```

Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: Sorry, I misread your question and did not realize you need *all* tags to match. I know how to do this with straight SQL but I'll have to think about how to do it with NHibernate... I've deleted my incorrect answer in the meantime.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can definitely do this with HQL; I've successfully tested it.

```
var items = session.CreateQuery("SELECT i.Id FROM Item i JOIN i.Tags tags WHERE tags.Name IN(:tags) GROUP BY i HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT tags) = :tagCount")
        .SetParameterList("tags", tagNames)
        .SetInt32("tagCount", tagNames.Count)
        .List();
```

That will get you a list of `Item` IDs which you can use to get the `Item`s.  The `GROUP BY` and `HAVING` combination *may* be inefficient on some DBMS though. There is another query method using iterative joins that *may* be more efficient on certain DBMS but I can't get it to work (may not be possible at all with Criteria). If I ever do, I'll update my answer.

Comment: This works, thanks.  For future reference, what systems might this be inefficient on?

Comment: The mysql.com site suggests that it will cause MySQL to use a temporary table with filesort: http://forge.mysql.com/wiki/TagSchema#Items_Having_All_of_A_Set_of_Tags However, that could be out of date or may have been improved... I have not done any extensive analysis and don't know enough about query engines in general to say if this is a common issue so that's why I stressed *may* :)