# Nhibernate QueryOver - Performing a Has All for a Many-to-Many relationship

Tags: c#, nhibernate, many-to-many, queryover

To explain my problem more easily I will create the following fictional example, illustrating a very basic many-to-many relationship.  A **Car** can have many **Parts**, and a **Part** can belong to many **Cars**.

**DB SCHEMA:**

```
CAR_TABLE
---------
CarId
ModelName

CAR_PARTS_TABLE
---------------
CarId
PartId

PARTS_TABLE
-----------
PartId
PartName
```

**CLASSES:**

```
public class Car 
{
  public int CarId {get;set;}
  public string Name {get;set;}
  public IEnumerable<Part> Parts {get;set;}
}

public class Part 
{
  public int PartId {get;set;}
  public string Name {get;set}
}
```

Using this very simple model I would like to get any cars that have all the parts assigned to them from a list of parts I am searching on.

So say I have an array of PartIds:

```
var partIds = new [] { 1, 3, 10};
```

I want to mimic the following c# code in terms of a database call:

```
var allCars = /* code to retrieve all cars */

var results = new List<Car>();

foreach (var car in allCars) 
{
  var containsAllParts = true;

  foreach (var carPart in car.Parts)
  {
    if (false == partIds.Contains(carPart.PartId))
    {
      containsAllParts = false;
      break;
    }
  }

  if (containsAllParts)
  {
    results.Add(car);
  }
}

return results;
```

To be clear: I want to get the Cars that have ALL of the Parts specified from the partIds array.

I have the following query, which is REALLY inefficient as it creates a subquery for each id within the partIds array and then does an IsIn query on each of their results. I am desperate to find a much more efficient manner to execute this query.

```
Car carAlias = null;
Part partAlias = null;

var searchCriteria = session.QueryOver<Car>(() => carAlias);

foreach (var partId in partIds)
{
  var carsWithPartCriteria = QueryOver.Of<Car>(() => carAlias)
    .JoinAlias(() => carAlias.Parts, () => partAlias)
    .Where(() => partAlias.PartId == partId)
    .Select(Projections.Distinct(Projections.Id()));

  searchCriteria = searchCriteria
    .And(Subqueries.WhereProperty(() => carAlias.Id).In(carsWithPartCriteria));
}

var results = searchCriteria.List<Car>();
```

Is there a decent way to execute this sort of query using NHibernate?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This should be exactly what you want...

```
Part part =  null;
Car car = null;
var qoParts = QueryOver.Of<Part>(() => part)
                .WhereRestrictionOn(x => x.PartId).IsIn(partIds)
                .JoinQueryOver(x => x.Cars, () => car)
                .Where(Restrictions.Eq(Projections.Count(() => car.CarId), partIds.Length))
                .Select(Projections.Group(() => car.CarId));
```

Comment: Very clever to reverse the query path to start from the context of Parts.  :)  I will try this and let you know.  Thanks.

Comment: Works perfectly and way way more efficiently. x

Answer (score 3):

```
Part partAlias=null;
Session.QueryOver<Car>().JoinQueryOver(x=>x.Parts,()=>partAlias)
.WhereRestrictionOn(()=>partAlias.Id).IsIn(partIds)  //partIds should be implement an ICollection
.List<Car>();
```

Hope that helps.

Comment: Sorry, I have re-reviewed this as I have needed it and this does not solve my problem. I need all cars with ALL of the parts in the provided array, not cars that have ANY the parts specified in the array.  Apologies!

Answer (score 0):

modified version of this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/953461/40822)

```
var cars = session.CreateQuery("SELECT c.id FROM Car c JOIN c.Parts p WHERE p.PartId IN(:parts) GROUP BY c HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT p) = :partsCount")
        .SetParameterList("parts", partIds)
        .SetInt32("partsCount", partIds.Count)
        .List();
```

AFAIK the `having` clause is only available in HQL. You could modify the select/group by list if you want more columns. Another possible way would be too generate an HQL query that inner joins to each specific part id. I don't think that is possible with ICritiria either as it only lets you join to a property once.